# Custom debug messages in the terminal?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, terminal

**TL;DR** I am writing an application in C++ in Visual Studio and I spend a lot of time in the terminal sending commands and debugging.  Is it possible to customize the terminal in terms of debug messages without hardcoding `std::cout` everywhere and writing my own terminal from scratch?

My application regularly sends information and error messages to the terminal and I have formatted it decently using `std::cout` and `\n`.  However, this feels really clunky and does not always work out nicely.  My team will also be using the terminal so I want it to be a nice experience.

For example, I want to have an output that says `[APP] [INPUT] :` every time I want to enter a command, and a line that says `[OPENGL] [INFO] :` every time I print OpenGL information.
As I said, I have already done this with `std::cout`, but I just want to know if there is a better way?

**I was thinking something along the lines of having a default message that prints after messages have been printed in the terminal and it is stagnant for x amount of time.  That way I can have my `[APP] [INPUT] :` message.**

---

**Edit 1**

My error handling and information printing are handled by functions, as suggested by Richard.

Comment: Put your tracing /debugging into functions that add the prefix.

Comment: Maybe you're interested in using a specific logging library (e.g. log4cpp) where you can control a number of things programmatically, and via config files.

Comment: If you want to retain the streaming API (i.  e. using `operator<<`) you could have a separate logger class for that forwards to `std::cout` or any arbitrary other stream. The opening string might be printed in constructor, and destructor might append a newline. Streaming API is pretty unhandy to create formatted output, though...

Comment: The streaming API is a rather low level one. What you want here is a *logging* system. You can either look for existing libraries, or roll your own. What really matters is what you exactly want. Once encapsulated in a class, it will be much easier to use.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, a logging library! Thank you very much.  You can add the answer if you want to, otherwise I am going to do it, for the sake of completeness.